# Getting 500 Response on Python Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

```
import requests

url = "https://uk.eu-supply.com/ctm/supplier/publictenders?B=BLUELIGHT"

payload={'Branding': 'BLUELIGHT',
'SearchFilter.BrandingCode': 'BLUELIGHT',
'CpvContainer.CpvIds': '',
'CpvContainer.CpvIds': '',
'SearchFilter.PagingInfo.PageNumber': '2',
'SearchFilter.PagingInfo.PageSize': '25'}
files=[

]
headers = {
  'Cookie': 'EUSSESSION=e3cc7bc4-ea51-4c4b-99f7-2ebde589c8e0'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.status_code)

eu-supply.com
https://uk.eu-supply.com
```

I am trying to hit request to this site, the same payload and url request works with postman. Notice (two same fields on payload **"CpvContainer.CpvIds**", this is must. In order to get 200 response , we need to pass this field twice. But as dict can only set one key unique. I am getting 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the repeated key's values as a list:

```
payload={
...
'CpvContainer.CpvIds': ['',''],
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To read a table from the page, simple `pd.read_html` is enought:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://uk.eu-supply.com/ctm/supplier/publictenders?B=BLUELIGHT"

df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Quote/tender Id           Reference                                                                                                           Name Date of publication Response deadline (UK time)                                                Process                                            Buyers       Countries
0             45024       7F- 2020-0278                                           Kennelling of Seized & Dangerous Dogs (Kent Police and Essex Police)          25/06/2021            26/07/2021 12:00                         Above Threshold OPEN Procedure                              7 Forces Procurement  United Kingdom
1             45074            CONT0056                                                                                Leaflets for Crime Commissioner          25/06/2021            05/07/2021 12:00               Tender/Quotation (below Threshold value)                             Leicestershire Police  United Kingdom
2             45072        7F-2021-P038                                                            Bury St Edmunds Police Station - Car Park Extension          25/06/2021            26/07/2021 12:00    Formal Tender/Quotation (Advertised) (over £50,000)                              7 Forces Procurement  United Kingdom
3             44234    7F - 2020 - 0387                                                                      Fire Doors Inspection and Maintenance PMA          24/06/2021            26/07/2021 10:00                         Above Threshold OPEN Procedure                              7 Forces Procurement  United Kingdom
4             45068        7F-2021-P040                                                           Armoury Improvements- Bury St Edmunds Police Station          24/06/2021            26/07/2021 12:00    Formal Tender/Quotation (Advertised) (over £50,000)                              7 Forces Procurement  United Kingdom
5             45042    BLC-Aviation-003                                  Provision of Police Aviation Services including a Fleet Replacement Programme          23/06/2021            06/07/2021 12:00            Prior Information Notice (PIN) (Standalone)                              BlueLight Commercial  United Kingdom
6             42896              DP0570                                                          Reactive Mechanical Services and Small Works Projects          23/06/2021            03/08/2021 12:00                         Above Threshold OPEN Procedure  The Police and Crime Commissioner for Derbyshire  United Kingdom
7             45043    BLC-Aviation-003  Market Engagement Event for the Provision of Police Aviation Services including a Fleet Replacement Programme          23/06/2021            06/07/2021 12:00           Request for Information /Market Consultation                              BlueLight Commercial  United Kingdom
8             44914          20-21 EM15                                                                          Asbestos Management Services Contract          22/06/2021            20/07/2021 12:00  Formal Tender/Quotation (Advertised) ( up to £50,000)     Tyne and Wear Fire and Rescue Service (TWFRS)  United Kingdom
9             44793           1363-2016                                                                  Recovery of loose, stray and abandoned horses          21/06/2021            21/07/2021 14:00            Prior Information Notice (PIN) (Standalone)                 West Yorkshire Combined Authority  United Kingdom
10            44734        7F 2020 0339                                                                               Bodyshop Replacement and Repairs          21/06/2021            23/07/2021 12:00                         Above Threshold OPEN Procedure                              7 Forces Procurement  United Kingdom
11            44984                 NaN                                    Integrated Communications Control System (ICCS) for Northamptonshire Police          18/06/2021            30/06/2021 17:00            Prior Information Notice (PIN) (Standalone)                      MINT Commercial Services LLP  United Kingdom
12            44983             WMP0126                                                         Garage Equipment - Maintenance, Calibration and Repair          18/06/2021            19/07/2021 12:00               Tender/Quotation (below Threshold value)                              West Midlands Police  United Kingdom
13            44962  DHR Chair & Author                                                                        Domestic Homicide Review Chair & Author          17/06/2021            05/07/2021 12:00            Prior Information Notice (PIN) (Standalone)                              7 Forces Procurement  United Kingdom
14            44950                1197                                        Access Control/Automated Security Gate Maintenance and Related Services          17/06/2021            23/07/2021 14:00    Formal Tender/Quotation (Advertised) (over £50,000)                    Royal Berkshire Fire Authority  United Kingdom
15            44959             627_RFI                                                                      Evidence Based Practice Partnership Board          17/06/2021            16/07/2021 17:00           Request for Information /Market Consultation     Chief Constable for Devon and Cornwall Police  United Kingdom
16            44944                W344                                                                            Repair & Maintenance of UPS Systems          16/06/2021            13/07/2021 12:00               Tender/Quotation (below Threshold value)                                Northumbria Police  United Kingdom
17            44942        7F-2021-C058                                                                       Specialist Accredited Fire Investigation          16/06/2021            30/06/2021 12:00           Request for Information /Market Consultation                              7 Forces Procurement  United Kingdom
18            44916       WYP/CS/019/JB                                                                                          Fire Risk Assessments          16/06/2021            30/06/2021 14:00  Formal Tender/Quotation (Advertised) ( up to £50,000)                 West Yorkshire Combined Authority  United Kingdom
19            44594        7F-2020-0273                                                                      Norfolk Integrated Domestic Abuse Service          15/06/2021            20/07/2021 12:00                         Above Threshold OPEN Procedure                              7 Forces Procurement  United Kingdom
20            44911                SPCC                                    Sussex PCC RfQ - An evaluation for the domestic abuse perpetrator programme          15/06/2021            30/06/2021 12:00  Formal Tender/Quotation (Advertised) ( up to £50,000)  Office of the Sussex Police & Crime Commissioner  United Kingdom
21            44543           2420-2021       Force Medical Advisor (FMA) / Selected Medical Practitioner (SMP) and other Occupational Health Services          15/06/2021            14/07/2021 13:00                         Above Threshold OPEN Procedure                 West Yorkshire Combined Authority  United Kingdom
22            44845             C003196                                                     THERAPEUTIC INTERVENTIONS AND TRAINING PROVISION FOR WMFRA          15/06/2021            06/07/2021 16:00    Formal Tender/Quotation (Advertised) (over £30,000)           West Midlands Fire and Rescue Authority  United Kingdom
23            44544            ESFA0199                                                          CMI Leadership and Management Online Training Courses          14/06/2021            09/07/2021 12:00    Formal Tender/Quotation (Advertised) (over £25,000)                        East Sussex Fire Authority  United Kingdom
24            44714                 590                                                        Regional Grounds Maintenance and Winter Salting Service          11/06/2021            15/07/2021 12:00                         Above Threshold OPEN Procedure     Chief Constable for Devon and Cornwall Police  United Kingdom
```

Comment: as we need to pass the payload for pagination.

Answer (score 1):

In the above API use the payload as raw text. I cross-checked the below code is successfully fetching the data

```
import requests

url = "https://uk.eu-supply.com/ctm/Supplier/publictenders/PublicTenders"

payload="Branding=BLUELIGHT&SearchFilter.BrandingCode=BLUELIGHT&CpvContainer.CpvIds=&CpvContainer.CpvIds=&SearchFilter.PagingInfo.PageNumber=2&SearchFilter.PagingInfo.PageSize=25"
headers = {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'Origin': 'https://uk.eu-supply.com',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
  'Referer': 'https://uk.eu-supply.com/ctm/supplier/publictenders?B=BLUELIGHT',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'Cookie': 'EUSSESSION=b18ce90d-32b9-429c-8d74-7151a997e8cd'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Thats great. Thank you 

Comment: @SudipAdhikari if it helped you, please accept my answer.